# How can I bitshift a 0 bit?

Tags: binary, hex, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to bitshift like this in order. Is there a logical operation that can help me do this?

```
0111 1111
1011 1111
1101 1111
1110 1111
1111 0111
1111 1011
1111 1101
1111 1110
```

For hexadecimal, it would be

```
0x7F
0xBF 
0xDF 
0xEF 
0xF7 
0xFB 
0xFD 
0xFE
```

Comment: Is `1111 1110` shift should lead to `0111 1111`?

Comment: What language do you want to use? There are rotate (ror, rol) instructions in assembly that could do this. Otherwise I would use a language's bit shifting (i.e. >>) operator in combination with either saving bit zero and placing it in bit 7 after the shift, or always filling bit 7 with a 1 if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Vitalii  1111 1110 goes back to 1111 1101

Comment: @GregH I am using C language. I didn't quite understand. Sorry, my english is not that great. Could you perhaps show it by logical operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for 8 bit numbers (example works for Java, may be helpful for С too)

```java
value = ((value >> 1) & 0x7F) | 0x80
```

And this one for back propagation of zero

```java
value = ((value << 1) | 1) & 0xFF
```